# How to use jsf add message when using executor service?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display friendly  error message in the browser when an exception happens in the thread. I have  (similar to h:message) in the xhtml page. It displays the message as long it is from same thread, but it don't work in this scenario. How to make this working without holding the thread, as the method should execute asynchronously?

```
public void start(final Land lan)
    {
        try {
            Future future = executor.submit(new Callable(){
                @Override
                public Object call() {
                    try {
                        conversion.processLand(lan);
                        LOG.debug("Finished the execution serverion");
                        uploadLandPages(lan.getPages(),
                                lan.getLandOID());
                    }catch(LanException doc){
                        LOG.error("LanException is caused due to "+doc.getMessage());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"File Conversion Issue","Unfortunately we cannot convert this file, please try again later"));
                    } catch (ApplicationException apx) {
                        LOG.error("ApplicationException is caused due to "+apx.getMessage());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"File Conversion Issue", "We have successfully converted the file but couldn't save in our server"));
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e){
            LOG.error("Exception caused in the thread which converts the doc due to {}",e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't create the Conversion thread");
        }
            finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because the message has to go in the HTTP response. When you leave the thread serving the HTTP request with the intent to run asynchronously, you -obviously- lose control over the HTTP response. Even more, the `FacesContext` is not available in the other thread at all. The particular code would only end up in a `NullPointerException`.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Use polling. You can use [`<p:poll>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) for that. Poll in intervals to a session scoped bean as long as until there's a non-null message present. Then remove and display it and stop polling. The executor service should set the message as a property of that session scoped bean.
2. Use pushing. You can use [`<p:socket>` (PrimePush)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) for that. The executor should set the message via `PushContext#push()` on an unique channel name as identified by `<p:socket channel>` (unique to the current user! or it may reflect to all users).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as you seem to be using Java EE already, I suggest to use `@Asynchronous` EJB method instead of executor service, if possible. This way the threads are managed and pooled by the container itself.